# Spring configure two @Endpoint, each with a unique wsdl file

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws, endpoint

I've been able to get one @Endpoint with a wsdl file working:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class EventServerConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/event");
    }


    @Bean(name = "wsdl-event")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("/wsdl/event.wsdl"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    AnnotationActionEndpointMapping endpointMapping() {
        AnnotationActionEndpointMapping mapping = new AnnotationActionEndpointMapping();
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

But for my use case I have two wsdl files that I need to handle. Originally I set up a RestController and unmarshalled the body from a xml POST request, but I now want to try the pure spring way.

I assume I need to create two MessageDispatcherServlet, one for each wsdl definition, but I have no idea how to map or register my endpoints correctly.

Any ideas?

Fiddling around I created duplicate (with different wsdl and bean names) `WSDLdefinition` beans, and `messageDispatcherServlet` through `ServletRegistrationBean` has given me the error `Servlet messageDispatcherServlet was not registered (possibly already registered?)` while my endpoints seem to show up, but spring returns a 404 on any request to said endpoints.

Spring-ws version: 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My assumption was that I needed different paths for each Spring @Enpoint class. I realise now that I only need to register one `MessageDispatcherServlet` and define the wsdl files required to handle incoming requests.

Since I need two different wsdl files, I can support both by creating one `ServletRegistrationBean` that holds a `MessageDispatcherServlet`, two `Wsdl11Definition` beans (one for each wsdl file), and in my @Endpoint class I set the namespace and localPart as a part of the `@PayloadRoot` annotation.

Configuration class

```
// Configuration class
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration 
{
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
    {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/soap");
    }

    @Bean
    AnnotationActionEndpointMapping annotationActionEndpointMapping() 
    {
        AnnotationActionEndpointMapping mapping = new AnnotationActionEndpointMapping();
        // add any interceptors here for features like logging
        return mapping;
    }

    // wsdl file A
    @Bean(name="wsdl-definition-A")
    public Wsdl11Definition wsdl11DefinitionA()
    {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition def = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/A.wsdl"));

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    // wsdl file B
    @Bean(name="wsdl-definition-B")
    public Wsdl11Definition wsdl11DefinitionA()
    {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition def = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/B.wsdl"));

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
}
```

If you require different paths to your endpoints in stead of one. I *assume* you would need to tweak the `ServletRegistrationBean` defined above. Now everything is mapped to `"/soap"`.

And here are the endpoints:

```
@Endpoint
public class AServer
{
    private final static String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://some.namespace/v3/idk/am/i/even/real";
    private final static String LOCALPART = "XMLElementName";
    private final SomeMarshaller marshaller;

    @Autowired
    public EventServer(EventReceiveMarshaller marshaller) 
    {
        // I use a marshaller class to simplify my life
        this.marshaller = marshaller; 
    }

    @Override
    @ResponsePayload
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = LOCALPART)
    public JAXBElement<SomeResponseMessageType> triggerResponse(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<SomeRequestMessageType> msg) {

        // do something with the `msg` request

        // Send a OK response
        return this.marshaller.createReply(msg);
    }
}
```

And then `BServer` is exactly the same as `AServer` except the `NAMESPACE_URI` and `LOCALPART` as those depend on their respective wsdl files.

Comment: Hello, I've have the same configuration (one soap WebService with multiple wsdl and endpoints). The solution you give does the job, but in my case I couldn't get generated wsdl. The fix keep wsdl beeing generated and displayed is to change the url mapping declared in the instanciation of the ServletRegistrationBean from "/soap" to "/soap/*"

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081712/servletregistrationbean-doesnt-works-for-the-multiple-url-mapping-paths